# Minimal polynomial problem

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Show that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2 + i)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, i)$ and find minimal polynomial.

My question: Assume that they are equal, then the minimal polynomial of both sides must be the same. To prove and to find the minimal polynomial, I can do both at the same time.

LHS: let $u = \sqrt 2 +i\\u^2=1-2\sqrt2 i\\u^2-1=-2\sqrt2 i\\u^4-2u^2+1=-8
\\u^4-2u^2-9=0$.

Hence $t^4-2t^2-9$ is minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2 +i$

RHS: $\sqrt2 , i$ are roots of a polynomial, $(t^2-2)(t^2+1)=t^4-t^2-2$

It  is not the same with LHS. What is wrong? Please, help me

Comment: Minimal polynomials are defined with respect to single elements. It doesn't make sense to ask for the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}$ and $i$.

Comment: If it is so, what does it mean by saying $L=K(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ is extension field of K where $\alpha_i$ are distinct roots of a polynomial in K[x]?

Answer (score 2):

The 'minimal polynomial' (in the sense you imply) need not be the same.  In other words, a field extension can very easily be the splitting field for two different polynomials.

A simpler example is that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+1)$, but the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}$ is $t^2-2$, while the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+1$ is $t^2-2t-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2 + i) \subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, i)$ is obvious.

2) Show that the degree of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, i)$ over $\mathbb Q$ is 4.

3) You have already shown that the degree of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2 + i)$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\leq 4$ (why?)

4) Use the multiplicativity of degrees of field extensions.